# Find a number in an array that is twice as big as any other in linear time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, big-o

I have been tasked to improve my algorithm that finds a number that is twice as big as any other number in an array. It currently runs in O(n^2) and i need to make it run in O(n).

```
func twiceAsOldExact(p []person) bool {
for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
    for j := 0; j < len(p); j++ {
        if j == i {
            continue
        }
        if p[i].age == 2*p[j].age {
            return true
        }
    }
}
return false
}
```

I have thought about sorting the array using Counting Sort and work from there, however i am not sure if that will work.

Say that i have this array `a := []int{4,5,12,24}`

The algorithm should return true because 24 is twice as big as 12.

If the array was `a := []int{4,8,10,16}`

It would return true either because of 8 that is twice as big as 4, or 16 that is twice as big as 8, depending what completes the check first.

Do any of you have any pointers on how should i tackle this problem? Partial solution is fine, or just advice, since it's for an interview perhaps it's not moral to ask for outside help (although that's what i would do in work).

Best regards!

Proposed Solution

```
func twiceAsOldExact2(p []person) bool {
    m := make(map[int]int)
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        m[p[i].age] = i
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        if _, ok := m[2*p[i].age]; ok {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Yes linear scan, search for 2 maximal numbers, `max1` and `max2`. Thereafter, compare - is max1 >= 2*max2. If not - there is not exist such number, which 2x more than any other. If yes - return the `max1`.

Comment: @olegarch what would happen if the array was `a := []int{8,4,20,18}` max1 would be 20 and max2 would be 18 and that would return false. However 8 is twice as big as 4.

Comment: @user3386109 i updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put values into map, and for every value `x` check whether `2*x` presents in the map.

Inserting into a map (implemented as hashtable) and searching takes in average O(1) per operation, so map approach is close to linear O(n) and it is much faster than quadratic O(n^2) two-loops one (but uses memory)

Comment: Isn't that like offloading the second for loop to the Go runtime? Does it perform better because it's a map?

Comment: I added complexity clues

Comment: Something like my proposed solution (in the original post)?

Comment: You can use the only for-loop, checking immediately before adding.`for ... if m[2*p[i].age] exists return true else  m[p[i].age] =1`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, returns false for the same array.

Comment: I am not familiar with Go. Is `if` operator correct? Should not it look like `_, ok := m[2*p[i].age]; if ok return true`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222803/discussion-between-alex-tselikas-and-mbo).

Comment: @Alex Tselikas Sorry, too late for me

Comment: This only works for slices sorted in descending order. For unsorted slices you also have to check n/2 if n is even.

Answer (score 3):

Copy your array into hash table, thereafter search for 2x in that hashtable. All is O(N), since N elements, and hash table insert and search is O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately i cannot choose two answers. How would i go about finding also ATLEAST as big as any other. For example `a := []int{5,11,6}` should return true because 11 is atleast twice as big as 5.

Comment: @Alex Tselikas ATLEAST is completely another problem and requires finding min and max

Comment: @MBo something like, find min and max and if max is >= 2*min then return true?

Comment: Yes, exactly (for all positive values)